# retrieving all entries using a REST API

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I know there's loads of questions about REST API pagination. Mine is a little different.

I wrote this script to pull out a particular piece of information from [this](http://data.rcsb.org/rest/v1/core/entry/5XTI) page:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://data.rcsb.org/rest/v1/core/entry/5XTI'
r = requests.get(url)
json_data = json.loads(r.text)
print(json_data['rcsb_entry_info']['polymer_entity_count_protein'])
```

However, this website has >250,000 entries (i.e. replacing the '5XTI' in the URL with 250,000 other accessions), and I want the script to run through all of the pages (i.e. something like: 'http://data.rcsb.org/rest/v1/core/entry/*'); is there a generic way to do this (or is it specific to the API?)

I wouldn't have a list of all the IDs to run through beforehand (i.e. i can't just make a list of them all and run through the list).

Comment: With not having a list with the IDs you only could brut force through them is that possible?

Comment: Do you have access to other entries id like `5XTI`? How do you navigate to this page?

Comment: If you do not have a way to get these IDs then answer to your question is No because `http://data.rcsb.org/rest/v1/core/entry/*` does not allow indexing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the list of all PDB IDs [here](https://www.rcsb.org/pages/general/summaries). So just pull that and read that into your loop.

Also note, requests incorporates the `json.loads()`, so you don't need to do that separately. Just include that in your `requests.get()`

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "ftp://ftp.wwpdb.org/pub/pdb/derived_data/index/author.idx"
indexfile = pd.read_csv(url, skiprows=3,sep=";")

for pdb_id in list(indexfile['IDCODE']):
    url = 'http://data.rcsb.org/rest/v1/core/entry/%s' %pdb_id.strip()
    json_data = requests.get(url).json()

    count = json_data['rcsb_entry_info']['polymer_entity_count_protein']

    print('%s: %s' %(pdb_id, count))
```

**Output:**

```
5G5D : 2
4BT2 : 1
4BT3 : 1
4BT4 : 1
4BT5 : 1
4BT6 : 1
4BT7 : 1
3V95 : 1
2PYH : 1
6F7E : 1
6SO0 : 1
6HFZ : 1
6HH9 : 1
2PYG : 1
2KV1 : 1
2L1U : 1
2LHS : 1
2ML1 : 1
2ML2 : 1
2ML3 : 1
2NPB : 1
2AGM : 1
5FOH : 1
5LW4 : 1
5LFO : 1
5LGB : 1
5MBX : 1
...
```